# how to send data-id value to function

Tags: jquery

I parse the json incoming data and transfer it to the table by append method. I open the new screen when I click on the table row, but I can not send the id value that I clicked.

that js

```
   function fisYukle(dt) {
            $('#tblFisList').empty();
            $.each(dt, function (i, dt) {
                $('#tblFisList').append("<tr onclick=fisAyrinti();return false;><td data-id=fis>" +
                    dt.ID + "</td><td>" +
                    dt.Evrakno + "</td><td>" +
                    dt.EvrakTarih + "</td><td>" +
                    dt.MagazaAd + "</td><td>" +
                    dt.Tutar + "</td></></tr>");
            })
        }
```

that's fisAyrinti() function

```
 function fisAyrinti(data-id) {
        $('#fisGizliID')[0].innerText = data-id;
        $('#modal1').modal('open');
    }
```

how to pass data-id to function (id in clicked row)? thanx

Comment: you are not passing any argument from function fisAyrinti() in tr tag

Comment: `data-id` is not a valid variable name. You should really check the console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are appending the `tr` you have not passed any argument to the function bound with it.

```
<tr onclick=fisAyrinti(this);return false;><td data-id=fis>
```

You can see that I have passed `this` as an argument to the function, which will pass instance of the element. And inside the function you can take `data-id` using

```
function fisAyrinti(tag) {
    var data_id = $(tag).find('td:first').attr('data-id');
    $('#fisGizliID')[0].innerText = data_id;
    $('#modal1').modal('open');
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried your suggestion;
tag=tr ,  i want id row's id value (13,15,16...) thank you

data_id = undefined, tag = tr

Comment: @SerhatHalilSilsüpür, check my updated answer. It should work now.

Comment: hey dude you are wonderful... if you come turkey, i will order you turkish raki :)

Answer (score 0):

Change fisAyrinti() to fisAyrinti(this) in your tr tag. 
And your function should be like:

```
function fisAyrinti(ctrl) {
       var id =  $(ctrl +' td:first-child').data('id');
    }
```

Comment: hi, i tried your suggestion; but ctrl=tr is coming , i want id row's id value (13,15,16...) thank you

Comment: didn't work,  i debug with chrome(f12) ctrl=tr and var id= undefined

Comment: var id =  $(ctrl +' td:first-child').data('id');   syntax error